# Increment syntax: two pluses ain't as plus one? (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, increment

Why this example is **working**

```js
 showNext = () => {
    const { current, total } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      current: current + 1 === total ? 0 : current + 1
    });
  };
```

---

and this one is **not**

```js
 showNext = () => {
    const { current, total } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      current: current++ === total ? 0 : current++
    });
  };
```

---

And this one **isn't working too**

```js
  showNext = () => {
    const { current, total } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      current: ++current === total ? 0 : ++current
    });
  };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "working"?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Right! Got it...

Comment: Two last exapmles do error. And script ain't working. Fn is just a part of whole script.

Comment: ++current will increment and compare the value, but if you return ++current, it will return a double incremented value, A correct solution would be `current: ++current === total ? 0 : current`, however it isn't recommended to mutate state directly since it will lead to unexpected issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `var +1` creates a new variable that is evaluated and leaves `var` untouched.

Post and pre increment (`++var var++`) actually change the variable. So in these examples you are increasing the variable both when you evaluate it and when you assign it.